# Arithmetic on modular curves

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I had tried to read the first few pages of Glenn Stevens' *Arithmetic on Modular Curves*, but it is somehow extremely unreadable to me, the text format is odd and stating too much facts without explanation.

I think I might lack some background, so is there any other books which explain more on some similar topics or could help me understanding Glenn Stevens' *Arithmetic on Modular Curves* ?

Here is its table of contents:

[image]
[image]

Ps. I had read Serre's *A course in Arithmetic*, and have some basic knowledge of algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 3):

Another good reference is Diamond and Shurman's "A First Course in Modular Forms", or [William Stein's "Modular Forms"](http://wstein.org/books/modform/stein-modform.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Stevens' 1982 book is a research monograph, aimed at readers who are already experts. There's a big gap between it and Serre's book.

To bridge that gap, you might like to try reading some of the articles in the Cornell--Silverman--Stevens volume on  Fermat's last theorem (especially Rohrlich's article in that volume on modular curves). That and the references therein should help you to understand what's going on in *Arithmetic on Modular Curves*.